# Self-Employment in Germany with Blue Card after I quit my job

Tags: germany, blue-card, freelance

I am a US citizen with a Blue Card in Germany and held my job in Berlin for two years. I quit and told the Auslanderbehorde. They told me I have 6 months to look for a job. I found freelance opportunities in other countries like US and France to complete remotely. Am I allowed to do this while I look for other jobs? Do I need to report it on my German taxes and do I need to report it any other way? Or do I need to report it to the countries that the job is in?

My zusatzblatt says «Beschäftigung nicht gestattet mit Ausnahme der Tätigkeit als UX Design-Technologist. Selbständige Tätigkeit gestattet nach 2 Jährig. Versicherungspfl. Beschäftigt. Ist Beschäftig. Jeder Art Gestattet.

Comment: Yes, you may. Your Zusatzblat states that explicitly. **Self-employment permitted after 2 years of  insuranced employment.** And yes, you must pay income tax on your income. You also must have (and pay yourself) a full health insurance.